# Is Angular 3 first created in TypeScript?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Is Angularjs 3 based *first* upon TypeScript?  I say first because TypeScript "compiles" to Javascript.

Does this mean a developer can use TypeScript when using Angularjs (and specifically Angularjs 3)?

Comment: You can use TypeScript with almost any JS library via typings files.

Comment: Angular 3?? Thought they were at 2

Comment: And you can use anything you want, not limited to typescript, it works well with ES2015 and babel too.

Comment: 3?  Did I nod off and miss an entire release?  What happened to 2?

Comment: They are at 2 but 3 is coming in 2017.

Comment: The docs for Angular 2 allow you to choose JS, TS or Dart. It all transpiles down to plain JS anyway for the browser. I believe Angular itself is written in TS so if you have no requirement they recommend you use TS too. Who knows what Angular 3 will be written in.

Comment: Just to clarify, Angular 3 will not be a complete remake, they will use major version numbers for updates (instead of Angular 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 ..., there will be Angular 2, 3, 4 ...)

Comment: My reason for asking is because that is a huge endorsement of TypeScript.  I wanted to verify what I had read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Answer this you must understand the versioning of Angular 2 vs Angular 1

Angular 3 is the next release of Angular 2. Unlike Angular 1 to Angular 2 Angular 3 is like Angular 2.1 if you go by how Angular 1's versioning style.

This is a great Blog post to explain this.
https://toddmotto.com/please-stop-worrying-about-angular-3#real-versioning

With this in mind Angular 3 will be like Angular 2 Google will continue writing in TypeScript and pushing the use of TypeScript but you can write Angular 2 and 3 in both.

Comment: Do you see this as a big endorsement of TypeScript?  Angular seems to be one of the big boys.

Comment: I do see it as a big endorsement. 
The Angular team had to use a JavaScript compiler as Angular 2 is based on es6 and es7 features and you can't do that yet as older browsers don't support them.
So why TypeScript over something like Babel? In my opinion, type checking. TypeScript can do it and I have yet to see any other JavaScript compiler that can.
So in my mind it makes sense why they went the path they did.